# ASP MVC Upload helper extension issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, html-helper

I came across the following issue: 
I have this model

```
public class Region
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFile CustomFile { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a custom extension html helper method from [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1566760/4033836.aspx).

Now in the view I have the following code:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("ModifyRegion", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

{%>

```
  <%: Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.RegionID, Model.RegionID)%>
  <br />
  <%: Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.RegionName, Model.RegionName)%>
  <br />

 <%: Html.FileBoxFor(x=>x.CustomFile, Model.CustomFile) %>

<input type="submit" />
```

When it reaches my controller action the CustomFile field is empty, but all other fields are properly set. If I change the CustomFile property to string instead of HttpPostedFile, I get correctly the file name ("dog.jpg" for example). Is there any way to get the full HttpPostedFile file correctly?

Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `HttpPostedFile` by `HttpPostedFileBase` in your view model:

```
public class Region
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase CustomFile { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure that the custom `FileBoxFor` helper you are using generates correct name and type of the corresponding file field:

```
<input name="CustomFile" type="file" />
```

Comment: Tried that. The CustomFile property is still null. The generated HTML is :                                                      <form action="/Home/ModifyRegion" method="post"><form action="/Home/ModifyRegion" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
0</textarea>
      <br />
      <textarea cols="20" id="RegionName" name="RegionName"rows="2">
</textarea>
      <br />
     <input name="CustomFile" type="file" value="Browse" />
    <input type="submit" />
 </form></form>

Comment: @TamasIonut, seems like you have 2 nested forms which is invalid HTML. You will have to remove the outer form and leave only the one with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a partial view which declared a form itself and was embedded into my view into another form . (Don't know too much about HTML I guess ;)) )

Comment: And also if I change the type to HttpPostedFile it doesn't work. Only with HttpPostedFileBase. Good to know that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like :

< input name="CustomFile" type="file" value="Browse" />